# Select multiple conditions where one can be null

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-conditions

I'm passing several parameters to mysql query. Some of them can be "all" or "null". How can I use one query for that?

How can I pass, for example, action=ALL, user=3, what=ALL.
By ALL I mean all action possible options.

```
SELECT id, user, action, what, from_value, to_value, updated_date 
from history 
where (user=? and action=? and what=?) 
order by updated_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE field_name IS NULL` or `WHERE field_name IS NOT NULL` to specifically filter on whether or not something is `NULL`. If it doesn't matter what the value of a field is, you don't need to include it in your `WHERE` clause.

In your example, you're building a query based on POST data. If you want to filter on the value of `$h_action`, but it's okay if `$h_action` is null, you can do:

`WHERE (action = ? OR action IS NULL)`

And you can chain those together with `AND`s for multiple fields:

`WHERE (action = ? OR action IS NULL) AND (what = ? OR what IS NULL) AND ...` etc.

Comment: that's okay but what should be instead of "?". For example I pass $h_action = 'add' and query will do the select correctly.
But what if I pass $h_action = 'all'? I need to change the parameter "?" to something like "*"

Comment: Those `?`s represent your POST data, to be filled in via `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`.

Comment: ok, let's say I have three actions: all, add, edit. For exampl, I want to select specific user but action should be all. There's no such in DB, it means that I should select all actions. But I need to pass some param instead of "?". And it should mean "all", right?

Comment: Ah, I think I may understand now. There's no (neat) way to explicitly tell MySQL "any value is fine for this column" while also including that column in a `WHERE` clause. Your best solution would be to do extra PHP to check to see if `$h_action` is `all`; if it is, use a query that doesn't filter on the `action` column. That said, you can kind of trick MySQL by doing something like `WHERE action = CASE WHEN $h_action <> 'all' THEN $h_action ELSE action END` (replacing `$h_action` as necessary), but it's kinda gross.